# Is there a NuGet command to update package.config versions?

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to get `NuGet` to update versions in package.config to the latest available?

i.e. is there an equivalent command in `NuGet` for `npm`'s `npm update --save/--save-dev`?

Comment: I'd expect [`nuget update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update) to do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a NuGet command to update package.config versions?

You can use [Update-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package) on Package Manager Console window to update all packages to the latest version.

Alternatively, you can also use command with nuget.exe cli:

```
nuget update <configPath> [options]
```

where  identifies either a packages.config or solution file that lists the project's dependencies.